# 2D sprite rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I am making a unity game using C# but I want to know how to rotate the player. My 2D sprite falls over a lot but I want to fix it.

This is the code I tried:

```
transform.rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: well `transform.rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0);` means nothing else then ... starting from the current rotation the object has before this line rotate it about .. nothing. I suppose you rather wanted e.g. `transform.rotation = Quaternion.idendity;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you want to lock rotation of the attached rigid body? That's a setting in the inspector.